# mongoid as_document error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I am using mongoid with devise invitable,

after assigning roles to user I found the following error

"**undefined method `as_document' for Array **" , any suggestions ?

```
invitable = find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:email, attributes[:email])
invitable.attributes = attributes
# scope_id attribute does not set properly
invitable.roles.map {|r| r.scope_id = attributes[:roles_attributes]["0"][:scope_id]}

if invitable.persisted? && !invitable.invited?
  invitable.errors.add(:email, :taken)
elsif invitable.email.present? && invitable.email.match(Devise.email_regexp)
  invitable.invite!
end
```

Whats wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Facing the same error. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You posted code bud didn't tell us what line throws the error. Can you post the real stack trace or some more info?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because `as_document` doesn't work against an array, only single objects.

Comment: There is not enough code in your question to give further details or possible corrected version.

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer.  Try "whatever.first.as_document" where whatever is the object that you're trying to represent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Mongoid and has_many relationships.

The method 'as_document' has to be defined for has_many relationships, like it is defined for embeds_many relationships.

I am going to make a [pull request](https://github.com/mrjlynch/mongoid/commit/8d91cc7497fadb9967305d409630e8a0f25dcc0c) to have this issue fixed, in the meantime you can define mongoid in your gemfile like so:

```
gem 'mongoid', :git => https://github.com/mrjlynch.git
```

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me with MongoId 5.1.0 when, in one direction I had "**embeds_many**", and in the other direction I had "**belongs_to**".

From what I know, the reverse of embeds_many shall be **embedded_in**.
Changing the reverse relationship to **embedded_in** fixed that issue for me.

I have to admit, this is a very obscure error message.